# How do I make sure I'm updating the Q-values correctly?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to implement Q-Learning in python, but for some reason, the agent just doesn't move right now. Could it be a problem with how I'm updating the table?

Q-Learning class:

[image: Q-Learning class]

This is how I'm training it.

[image: Training]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)